# data sync between tables in 2 Databases by SSIS 2012

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in two Databases having identical schema. The two databases are on different servers at different location. Now the data can be inserted and updated in any of the two databases table. The requirement is to sync the two tables in different databases so that they are always having the updated information.

The primary key column will always be unique in either database table.

How to achieve this via SSIS ?

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with 2 `Script Tasks`. In the first one:

```
-- what exists in A and not in B
SELECT * INTO DB1.temp.TBL_A_except FROM
(
   SELECT pk FROM DB1.schema1.TBL_A
     EXCEPT
   SELECT pk FROM DB2.schema2.TBL_B
);
-- what exists in B and not in A
SELECT * INTO DB2.temp.TBL_B_except FROM
(
   SELECT pk FROM DB2.schema2.TBL_B
     EXCEPT
   SELECT pk FROM DB1.schema1.TBL_A
);
```

Second one:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.schema2.TBL_B
SELECT * FROM DB1.temp.TBL_A_except;

INSERT INTO DB1.schema1.TBL_A
SELECT * FROM DB2.schema2.TBL_B_except;

DROP TABLE DB1.temp.TBL_A_except;
DROP TABLE DB2.schema2.TBL_B;
```

If you **really** want to achieve this with SSIS transformation techniques, I'd use two data flows with 2x`Cache Connection Manager` as our temp table 1 and 2. First one to save data into cache, second to load from cache into tables.

or

Two data flows. `Source` -> `Lookup` -> `Destination`.
Implement lookup to check the second table for existance of PK. If for a record Tbl_A there is no such PK in Tbl_B it means you have to insert this row into Tbl_B. `No Match Output`, directs row to Destination.